# How to convert the below result into my required format

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

> I want to reformat the below result into the format I needed.
> Current result:

```
{
'1': [
{ Resource_id: 1, Rolemaching: 5 },
{ Resource_id: 1, Rolemaching: 5 },
{ Resource_id: 1, Technologymaching: 25 },
{ Resource_id: 1, Technologymaching: 25 },
{ Resource_id: 1, Educationmaching: 1.6666666666666667 },
{ Resource_id: 1, Educationmaching: 3.3333333333333335 }
],
'2': [ { Resource_id: 2, Domainmaching: 10 } ]
}
```

The format I needed

```
{
Resource_id : 1
Rolemaching : 10,
Technologymaching:25,
Educationmaching : 4.5
}
{
Resource_id : 2,
Domainmaching : 10
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you need inferring from your "The format I needed" example. But if you need all properties be summed (except `Resource_id`), this is a variant:

```js
const data1 = {
  '1': [
    { Resource_id: 1, Rolemaching: 5 },
    { Resource_id: 1, Rolemaching: 5 },
    { Resource_id: 1, Technologymaching: 25 },
    { Resource_id: 1, Technologymaching: 25 },
    { Resource_id: 1, Educationmaching: 1.6666666666666667 },
    { Resource_id: 1, Educationmaching: 3.3333333333333335 },
  ],
  '2': [
    { Resource_id: 2, Domainmaching: 10 },
  ],
};

const data2 = Object.values(data1).map(
  array => array.reduce(
    (acc, { Resource_id, ...rest }) => {
      acc.Resource_id ??= Resource_id;
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rest)) {
        acc[key] ??= 0;
        acc[key] += value;
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {},
  )
);

console.log(data2);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Resource_id": 1,
    "Rolemaching": 10,
    "Technologymaching": 50,
    "Educationmaching": 5
  },
  {
    "Resource_id": 2,
    "Domainmaching": 10
  }
]
```